# Is it possible to use an Azure JSON-View as part of a deployment script?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account, azure-cloud-shell, json-view

Azure newbie -
I manually created an azure data lake gen 2 storage account.  I clicked on the JSON View icon and was presented with a JSON string containing all the information about the storage account.  Is it possible to use that JSON string as part of a script to create the storage account?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datalakestore/accounts?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template), the ARM template to create ADLS account should be in the following format:

```json
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DataLakeStore/accounts",
  "apiVersion": "2016-11-01",
  "name": "string",
  "location": "string",
  "tags": {
    "tagName1": "tagValue1",
    "tagName2": "tagValue2"
  },
  "identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
  },
  "properties": {
    "defaultGroup": "string",
    "encryptionConfig": {
      "keyVaultMetaInfo": {
        "encryptionKeyName": "string",
        "encryptionKeyVersion": "string",
        "keyVaultResourceId": "string"
      },
      "type": "string"
    },
    "encryptionState": "string",
    "firewallAllowAzureIps": "string",
    "firewallRules": [
      {
        "name": "string",
        "properties": {
          "endIpAddress": "string",
          "startIpAddress": "string"
        }
      }
    ],
    "firewallState": "string",
    "newTier": "string",
    "trustedIdProviders": [
      {
        "name": "string",
        "properties": {
          "idProvider": "string"
        }
      }
    ],
    "trustedIdProviderState": "string",
    "virtualNetworkRules": [
      {
        "name": "string",
        "properties": {
          "subnetId": "string"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, the JSON view of ADLS is not in the required format, so it is not possible to use an Azure ADLS JSON-View as part of a deployment script. Modify the JSON according to the above format, save it as a JSON file, and upload it to PowerShell as shown below:

[image]

Execute the following command to deploy the ADLS account:

```bash
az deployment group create --resource-group "<resourceGroupName>" --template-file <fileName>.json
```

This will deploy the ADLS account as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not the right JSON. Most resources have an "Export Template" options in the Azure Portal on the lefthand menu in section "Automation" (See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal)). This allows you to generate the ARM template that can be used in a deployment pipeline or by running `az deployment` or a powershell command as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-tutorial-local-template?tabs=azure-powershell#deploy-template).

Example:

[image]